# Unexpected result from combinatory recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a sequence of natural numbers at specific power (`n`) until an upper limit (`x`) starting from 1. For example if the power is `n = 2` and `x = 5` the sequence is `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]`. Based on that numbers I have to find all the possible combinations as long as the sum of 1 or more values in a set returns `x`. Some examples:

- `[[1,4]]` for `x = 5` and `n = 2`
- `[[1,9]]` for `x = 10` and `n = 2`
- `[[1, 8, 27, 64]]` for `x = 100` and `n = 3`
- and so on

I wrote the following code:

```
combinations :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
combinations t l@(x:xs) a
    | sum l == t  = a ++ [l]
    | otherwise   = (map (x:) (combinations t xs a)) ++ (combinations t xs a)
combinations _ [] a = a

calcPowers x n = filter (<=x) (map (^n) [1..x])

combos x n = combinations x (calcPowers x n) []::[[Int]]
```

but the returned results are:

```
λ> combos 1 2
[[1]] -- CORRECT
λ> combos 4 2
[[1,4],[4]] -- WRONG
λ> combos 5 2
[[1,4]] -- CORRECT
λ> combos 10 2
[] -- this should be [[1,9]] -- WRONG
λ> combos 100 2
[[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100],[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,100],.....] -- WRONG
λ> combos 100 3
[[1,8,27,64]] -- CORRECT
```

Any idea why it is not returning the right sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(map (x:) (combinations t xs a))` is incorrect, since you will prepend x, the combination should match the remainder:

```
(map (x:) (combinations (t-x) xs a))
```

At some points `t` will become zero, and an empty list should produce a result for that zero.

```
combinations 0 [] a = []:a
combinations _ [] a = a
```